# Baixar imagens de uma lista txt(links) python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Primeiro importei os pacote e criei uma classe e suas definições:

```
class Scraper:
def __init__(self):
    self.visited = set()
    self.session = requests.Session()
    self.session.headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36"}
    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

def:

```
def visit_url(self, url, level):
    print(url)
    if url in self.visited:
        return
    self.visited.add(url)
    content = self.session.get(url, verify=False).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
    for img in soup.select("img[src]"):
        image_url = img["src"]
        if not image_url.startswith(("data:image", "javascript")):
            self.download_image(urljoin(url, image_url))
    if level > 0:
        for link in soup.select("[/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/a[1]/img]"):
            self.visit_url(urljoin(url, link["/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/a[1]/img"]), level - 1)
```

O download:

```
def download_image(self, image_url):
    local_filename = image_url.split('/')[-1].split("?")[0]
    r = self.session.get(image_url, stream=True, verify=False)
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            f.write(chunk)
```

O link:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
scraper = Scraper()
scraper.visit_url('https://mbasic.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=2498834290232454&id=198123623636877&refid=17&_ft_=mf_story_key.2498834290232454%3Atop_level_post_id.2498834290232454%3Atl_objid.2498834290232454%3Acontent_owner_id_new.198123623636877%3Athrowback_story_fbid.2498834290232454%3Apage_id.198123623636877%3Aphoto_attachments_list.%5B2498828320233051%2C2498828993566317%2C2498829400232943%5D%3Astory_location.4%3Astory_attachment_style.album%3Apage_insights.%7B%22198123623636877%22%3A%7B%22page_id%22%3A198123623636877%2C%22actor_id%22%3A198123623636877%2C%22dm%22%3A%7B%22isShare%22%3A0%2C%22originalPostOwnerID%22%3A0%7D%2C%22psn%22%3A%22EntStatusCreationStory%22%2C%22post_context%22%3A%7B%22object_fbtype%22%3A266%2C%22publish_time%22%3A1574031070%2C%22story_name%22%3A%22EntStatusCreationStory%22%2C%22story_fbid%22%3A%5B2498834290232454%5D%7D%2C%22role%22%3A1%2C%22sl%22%3A4%2C%22targets%22%3A%5B%7B%22actor_id%22%3A198123623636877%2C%22page_id%22%3A198123623636877%2C%22post_id%22%3A2498834290232454%2C%22role%22%3A1%2C%...', -1)
```

Mas gostaria de em vez do link, passar uma lista.txt com vários links, tem como, usando um laço de repetição?
As imagens que são baixadas do link no código:
[image: As imagens de um link apenas]
[image: O código executado]

Comment: Aparentemente você já fez o mais difícil, se quer usar um lista de urls de um arquivo, não bastaria você fazer um `for linha in arquivo` e usar `linha` como argumento para `download_image`? Qual é a sua dificuldade?

Comment: Porque fiz um outro código a parte, mas quando coloco a lista.txt no lugar de, scraper.visit_url(site aqui), baixa as imagens, mas corrompidas, porque baixa direto do link, sendo que cada link é preciso ser acessado para encontrar o path da imagem e aí sim baixar a imagem.

Comment: @HudsonSouza não coloque a resposta na pergunta.Você pode responder a sua própria pergunta como outro usuário.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f name == 'main':
arq = open(r'url.txt')
for i in arq:
    scraper = Scraper()
    scraper.visit_url(i, -1)
```

A solução, obrigado pela ajuda.